# Error:(7, 8) error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

This is my build.gradle settings:

```
ext {
    MIN_SDK_VERSION     = 14
    COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 23
    TARGET_SDK_VERSION  = 21
    BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '25.0.2'
    VERSION_CODE        = 1
    VERSION_NAME        = "1.0.a"
}
```

This is my dependencies block. I set up it to use v23:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

    compile ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview'
        exclude module: 'appcompat'
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile project(':MapboxAndroidSDK')
    compile('com.github.spurdow:rvlazyscroll:1.0.4') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview'
        exclude module: 'appcompat'
    }

    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview'
        exclude module: 'appcompat'
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I build the app:

```
Error:(7, 8) error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found
Error:(14, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(16, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(17, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(20, 34) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

This is the first time I'm seeing this problem, so is there a clean solution about this problem?

Comment: remove your support-v4 lib and add it again in this way , right click on the project > Android Tools > Add Support Library .

Comment: @Radhey im using android studio.

Comment: refer this discussion https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/684 .